# How can I encode a Codable type by specifying a subset of its CodingKeys?

Tags: swift, encoding

I have types for which I provide `CodingKeys` with custom names for their data members as appropriate. I would like to encode, as required by different call sites, only a subset of a type's `CodingKeys` before sending the data to a server. The required encodings change from call site to call site, so there's no default implementation to consider.

Example types (for demonstration purposes):

```
struct Account: Codable
{
    let name: String;
    var balance: Float;

    mutating func set(balance: Float)
    {
        self.balance = balance; // verifications, etc.
    }
}

struct User: Codable
{
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey
    {
        case
            id = "db_id",
            name = "db_name",
            account
            // many more keys
    }

    let id: Int;
    let name: String;
    var account: Account;
    // many more data members
}
```

Creating an instance:

```
var user = User(
    id: 1, name: "john", account: Account(name: "checking", balance: 10_000));
```

Using a `JSONEncoder` works as expected; it produces the following:

```
{
  "db_id" : 1,
  "db_name" : "john",
  "account" : {
    "balance" : 10000,
    "name" : "checking"
  }
}
```

I want to encode a subset of the `User` type in order to send that data back to a server so that I can update specific data fields instead of updating the entire set of properties of my type. Mock usage example:

```
user.account.set(balance: 15_000);
let jsonEncoding = JSONEncodeSubset.of(
    user, // instance to encode
    keys: [User.CodingKeys.id, User.CodingKeys.account] // data to include
);
```

The resulting produced JSON would look like so:

```
{
  "db_id" : 1,
  "account" : {
    "balance" : 15000,
    "name" : "checking"
  }
}
```

Server side, we now have the exact data we need to perform our desired update.

Another example: somebody entered the wrong name for our user, therefore another update request looks like this:

```
user.name = "jon"; // assume the model was modified to make this mutable
let jsonEncoding = JSONEncodeSubset.of(
    user, // instance to encode
    keys: [User.CodingKeys.id, User.CodingKeys.name] // only encode id & name
);
```

The expected resulting JSON encoding:

```
{
  "db_id" : 1,
  "name" : "jon"
}
```

Note that we exclude the information that isn't part of the update (user's account). The objective is to optimize the encoding to include only data that is relevant to that specific request.

Considering I have a large list of objects to update, with different call sites updating different things, I'd like to have a succinct way to perform the encoding task.

1. Encoding a subset of a type's data members improves encoding performance/memory footprint.
2. Sending a larger count of smaller encoded objects to the server becomes more efficient.

Does Swift provide any such support for encoding subsets of a type's `CodingKeys`?

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/using_json_with_custom_types

Comment: @Rob I understand how to provide custom encoding/decoding mappings when the models require it. I am specifically concerned with the encoding part; I need the encoding to be dynamic in terms of what data is encoded in different parts of the application. The decoding part can be implemented as in your links above without issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution requires that you write a custom `encode(to:)` for all properties but once that is done it should be easy to use.

The idea is to let the `encode(to:)` encode only those properties/keys that exists in a given array. So given the example above the function would look like this

```
func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    for key in selectedCodingKeys {
        switch key {
        case .id:
            try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
        case .account:
            try container.encode(account, forKey: .account)
        case .name:
            try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
            
        }
    }
}
```

`selectedCodingKeys` is new property in the struct

```
 var selectedCodingKeys = [CodingKeys]()
```

and we could also add a specific function for encoding

```
mutating func encode(for codingKeys: [CodingKeys]) throws -> Data {
    self.selectedCodingKeys = codingKeys
    return try JSONEncoder().encode(self)
}
```

and then the decoding could be done like in this example

```
var user = User(id: 1, name: "John", account: Account(name: "main", balance: 100.0))
do {
    let data1 = try user.encode(for: [.id, .account])
    let data2 = try user.encode(for: [.id, .name])
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on Joakim Danielson's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63080358/8697793) you can use `CodingUserInfoKey` to pass data to `userInfo` property of `JSONEncoder`.

```
extension CodingUserInfoKey {
    static let keysToEncode = CodingUserInfoKey(rawValue: "keysToEncode")!
}

extension JSONEncoder {
    func withEncodeSubset<CodingKeys>(keysToEncode: [CodingKeys]) -> JSONEncoder {
        userInfo[.keysToEncode] = keysToEncode
        return self
    }
}
```

You need to make `CodingKeys` conform to `CaseIterable` and implement a custom `encode(to:)` method:

```
struct User: Codable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey, CaseIterable { // add `CaseIterable`
        ...
    }
    ...
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        let keysToEncode = encoder.userInfo[.keysToEncode] as? [CodingKeys] ?? CodingKeys.allCases
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        for key in keysToEncode {
            switch key {
            case .id:
                try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
            case .account:
                try container.encode(account, forKey: .account)
            case .name:
                try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
let encoder = JSONEncoder().withEncodeSubset(keysToEncode: [User.CodingKeys.id, .account])
let encoded = try encoder.encode(user)

print(String(data: encoded, encoding: .utf8)!)
// prints: {"db_id":1,"account":{"name":"checking","balance":15000}}
```